# Python - Look for multiple words in a single cell from excel and add corresponding data to JSON using pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I'm trying to work on a project that is related to analytics and I'm trying to extract data out of an excel that looks something like this:

For some reason the uploading of image doesn't work so please bear with me as I try to put the excel data:

```
User ID | Transcript
9001      B: How are you?
          U: Show credit balance
          B: End

9002      B: How are you?
          U: Show bank statement
          B: End
```

1. I wanted to loop through the entire "Transcript" column and capture certain strings such as "Sample balance", "Bank statement", and "End" while putting in mind that the lines within this column are multiple.
2. Now if I see the data I need, I have to push or append a certain value in a JSON payload that would look something like this:

   {
   "SampleBal": 1, "BankSt": 1, "End": 2
   }

Here's what I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('export.xlsx')
new_df = df.loc[df['TRANSCRIPT'].str.contains('Bank statement', flags=re.I, regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

I'm fairly new to learning Python and was just wondering what are the next steps to make this possible by using pandas in Python?
Any help/guide is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you written code for *any* of this?

Comment: I forgot to add my code snippet, I edited it now. I just don't know what are the next steps to make especially for looping through the column. Maybe a brief guide or high level explanation on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have to much time right now, but I will write an explanation tonight. Maybe the snippet already helps, figuring it out.

```
import pandas as pd
dummyData = [
            {"Column 1": "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"},
            {"Column 1": "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4"} 
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dummyData)

print(df)
                         Column 1
0          Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3
1  Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4

searchWords = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 4"]

wordCount = {}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lines = row["Column 1"].split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        if line in searchWords:
            wordCount[line] = wordCount.get(line, 0) + 1
            
print(wordCount)

{'Line 1': 2, 'Line 2': 2, 'Line 4': 1}
```

Comment: Just wondering how would this work if there are words in between Line 1 like "Line 1 Word \n Line 2", would split still be applicable here?

Comment: I tried to put this snippet but instead of manually putting the data inside the dummyData array, I used pd.read_excel because I plan to read through an excel file. But it is returning an error on the for loop line (df.interrows()) saying that "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'interrows'.

Comment: To the first question, I would still do the split, but then instead of the if use a for loop over searchWord and use ```find()``` to check if the word or group of words is contained.

Comment: To the second, try ````.iteritems()``` instead of ```.iterrows()```  I think its the equivalent for DataFrames to Series